# Python list thread-safe on one writer to the end of list and one writer in the middle of the list

Tags: python-3.x

assume we have the following list and there are TWO writers only.

```
lst = [a, b, c]
```

One thread will modify items int the list; while another thread will keep appending new items to the end of the list.

Question> Is this thread-safe?

My guess is that this is thread-safe because the list append is atomic and the another thread only works on pre-existing items. Please correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: That depends on your notion of "thread safe". The runtime guarantees you that you'll get a valid list in any case. The contents of that list ... well.